# How to keep the state of a checkbox in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm tracking events (for data analytics purposes) and the current page I am looking at has multiple pop-up screens. I know it is confusing without seeing all the HTML so I will try to explain as best as I can, please bear with me:

1. When the `#verifyAccountBtn` is clicked, the first pop-up screen appears. It contains a check box.
2. If you click Continue on the first pop-up screen, a second pop-up screen appears, which includes a slider where you can toggle between 3 different slides on that pop-up.

Here is my code, and I will try to explain using comments as best I can what is happening:

```
// functions only execute if the pop-up overlay is present: 

 $(document).on("overlayIsVisible", function (e, overlayName) {

                var checkboxChecked = false;

                $(document).on("click", "#verifyAccountBtn", function () {
                    checkIfVerifyAccountPopUpVisible()
                })

                function checkClick() {
                    // #isVerificationUrgent is the checkbox id
                    $("#isVerificationUrgent").off().on('click', function () {
                        checkboxChecked = !checkboxChecked;
                        checkIfVerifyAccountPopUpVisible();
                    });
                }

                function checkIfVerifyAccountPopUpVisible() {

                    if ($("#verifyAccountReminder").hasClass('is-visible')) {
                        checkClick();
                        trackEvent();
                    }
                }

                function trackEvent() {
                   // data tracking code goes here which works. The next line is to track whether checkbox has been checked or not. 

                            'checkbox checked': checkboxChecked
                        });
                }

               // The following are the buttons to toggle between the next pop ups. 

                $('[aria-label="Go to slide 1"]').off().on('click', function () {
                    trackEvent();
                });
                $('[aria-label="Go to slide 2"]').off().on('click', function () {
                    trackEvent();
                });
                $('[aria-label="Go to slide 3"]').off().on('click', function () {
                    trackEvent();
                });
```

Currently, the checkbox property works for the first pop-up (which contains the checkbox) but this does not persist when the second checkbox appears and the status of `checkboxChecked` reverts to `false` (although I thought that the inclusion of the `checkboxChecked` variable would prevent this and it would remain as `true` if the checkbox was clicked on the first pop-up screen).

Can anyone please help me ensure that once the `checkboxChecked` property has changed to 'true', it will stay true whilst the user navigates through the rest of the pop-up screens?

Hopefully I explained that clearly enough. Any help is much appreciated, as I am relatively new to Javascript and JQuery. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post relevant code snippets of your HTML in your question too?